# Detect when any application Window is dragged to top of screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-10

On Windows 10 I have been experimenting with replacing the "Window snap" feature  to work better with ultra wide monitors. While I have had no problem capturing the Windows Key+arrow cursors to handle the keyboard shortcut, I now want to detect when another application Window has been dragged to the top/right/left/bottom of the current monitor.

Current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HHOOK _hook_keyboard;
KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct;

CONST int HORIZONTAL_SLOTS = 4;
CONST int VERTICAL_SLOTS = 1;

// horizontalPosition/verticalPosition specifies which "slot" starting at 0 to place Window in
// horizontalSlots/verticalSlots specifies how many slots to divide the screen into
void MoveAndResizeActiveWindow(int horizontalPosition, int verticalPosition, int horizontalSlots, int verticalSlots)
{
    // get work area on primary monitor
    HWND currentWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (currentWindow != NULL)
    {
        HMONITOR currentMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(currentWindow, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
        MONITORINFO monitorInfo;
        monitorInfo.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFO);
        if (GetMonitorInfo(currentMonitor, &monitorInfo))
        {
            long width = monitorInfo.rcWork.right - monitorInfo.rcWork.left;
            long height = monitorInfo.rcWork.bottom - monitorInfo.rcWork.top;
            long snappedWidth = width / horizontalSlots;
            long snappedHeight = height / verticalSlots;
            long snappedLeft = (snappedWidth * horizontalPosition) + monitorInfo.rcWork.left;
            long snappedTop = (snappedHeight * verticalPosition) + monitorInfo.rcWork.top;
            MoveWindow(currentWindow, snappedLeft, snappedTop, snappedWidth, snappedHeight, true);
        }
    }
}
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallbackKeyboard(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    BOOL bEatkeystroke = false;
    short keyState;

    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);

        switch (wParam)
        {
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN);
            if (keyState)
            {
                switch (kbdStruct.vkCode)
                {
                    case VK_LEFT:
                        bEatkeystroke = true;
                        break;
                    case VK_RIGHT:
                        bEatkeystroke = true;
                        break;
                    case VK_UP:
                        bEatkeystroke = true;
                        break;
                    case VK_DOWN:
                        bEatkeystroke = true;
                        break;
                };
            };
            break;
        case WM_KEYUP:
            keyState = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LWIN);
            if (keyState)
            {
                switch (kbdStruct.vkCode)
                {
                case VK_LEFT:
                    MoveAndResizeActiveWindow(0, 0, 4, 1);
                    bEatkeystroke = true;
                    break;
                case VK_RIGHT:
                    MoveAndResizeActiveWindow(3, 0, 4, 1);
                    bEatkeystroke = true;
                    break;
                    break;
                case VK_UP:
                    MoveAndResizeActiveWindow(1, 0, 4, 1);
                    bEatkeystroke = true;
                    break;
                case VK_DOWN:
                    MoveAndResizeActiveWindow(2, 0, 4, 1);
                    bEatkeystroke = true;
                    break;
                };
            }
            break;
        };
    }
    if (bEatkeystroke)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(_hook_keyboard, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

void SetHook()
{
    if (!(_hook_keyboard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallbackKeyboard, NULL, 0)))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to install hook on keyboard!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv[])
{
    SetHook();
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Any suggestions how to identify when Windows have been dragged to a particular location on the screen?

As per advice in replies to original question I have tried used SetWinEventHook with the following code, planning to restrict EVENT_MIN and EVENT_MAX once correct events to watch for worked out.

```
g_hook_winevent = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_MIN, EVENT_MAX, 
        NULL,                                          // Handle to DLL.
        HandleWinEvent,                                // The callback.
        0, 0,              // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
}

void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd,
    LONG idObject, LONG idChild,
    DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    // process event here

}
```

While this easily tracks start or end of a Windows move with EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART and EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND I can't see an event here that tracks the moving of Window prior to EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND.

While that will work if only good option, ideally I want to be able to detect Window location from start of EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART until EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND completes. Testing with notepad the only event getting raised during the move is EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE, which seems to constantly trigger during Window move, at least with Notepad. However based on description in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants) I'm not sure if this is suitable for my use case: "An object's Name property has changed. The system sends this event for the following user interface elements: check box, cursor, list-view control, push button, radio button, status bar control, tree view control, and window object. Server applications send this event for their accessible objects."

Comment: Look at [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook)

Comment: Thanks, added some additional info based on testing that API, if you have further idea let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE` and not `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE`? In any case, `SetWindowsHookEx()` also has hooks that can track window movements, such as `WH_CBT` and `WH_CALLWNDPROC/RET`